# SQL query multiple hotfixes

Tags: sql

So I have a query which I found on a dead post from a MS TechNet forum, which provides everything I need except for one thing, multiple KB hotfixes.

My current query finds all machines within a limited device collection with "x" update, however, I need the query to find all machines with "x AND y AND z".

```
select SMS_R_SYSTEM.ResourceID,SMS_R_SYSTEM.ResourceType,SMS_R_SYSTEM.Name,SMS_R_SYSTEM.SMSUniqueIdentifier,SMS_R_SYSTEM.ResourceDomainORWorkgroup,SMS_R_SYSTEM.Client 
from SMS_R_System 
 inner join SMS_G_System_QUICK_FIX_ENGINEERING on SMS_G_System_QUICK_FIX_ENGINEERING.ResourceId = SMS_R_System.ResourceId 
where SMS_G_System_QUICK_FIX_ENGINEERING.HotFixID = "KB4474419"
```

could something like the following work?

```
select SMS_R_SYSTEM.ResourceID,SMS_R_SYSTEM.ResourceType,SMS_R_SYSTEM.Name,SMS_R_SYSTEM.SMSUniqueIdentifier,SMS_R_SYSTEM.ResourceDomainORWorkgroup,SMS_R_SYSTEM.Client 
from SMS_R_System 
  inner join SMS_G_System_QUICK_FIX_ENGINEERING on SMS_G_System_QUICK_FIX_ENGINEERING.ResourceId = SMS_R_System.ResourceId 
where SMS_G_System_QUICK_FIX_ENGINEERING.HotFixID = "KB123","KB124","KB125"
```

Comment: Normal SQL syntax would be IN ('KB123','KB124','KB125')

Comment: Thanks OTTA, problem solved

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the `IN` operator:

```sql
where SMS_G_System_QUICK_FIX_ENGINEERING.HotFixID IN ('KB123','KB124','KB125')
```